# Как из списка вырезать все лишнее и каждый элемент записать с новой строки

Tags: python, синтаксис

код записывает его в файл с квадратными скобками и кавычками

```
# запись новых товаров в отдельный список
f = open('new_elem.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи  
json.dump(difference, f, ensure_ascii=False)
f.close()
```

Он записывает список вот такой

> ["Белое",  "Красное", "Синее" ]

Нужно что бы в файле был  вот такой список

```
Белое, 
Красное,
Синее
```

Comment: Либо так **json.dump(difference, f, ensure_ascii=False,indent = 1)**   либо в ручную. Так как вы разрушаете формат json

Comment: Спасиб. Половину сделал . Осталось лишние символы вырезать - кавычки и квадратные скобки. Мне этот фал только для записи в качестве текста. Поэтому формат JSON не важен. Но я по другому не знаю как записать в файл список таким способом

Comment: @Webos — вы **постоянно не оцениваете ответы на ваше вопроси** — из 10 правильных ответов вы приняли только 2. Может быть, что вы ещё не знаете, как получить список всех ваших вопросов. Кликните наверху на ваш аватар.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо использовать модуль `json` для простой записи элементов списка в файл:

```
with open('new_elem.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines([d + '\n' for d in difference])
```

---

Содержание файла `new_elem.txt` после хода этой программы:

> ```
> Белое
> Красное
> Синее
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Вместо `open`-`close` применено `with open` (контекст менеджер), также файл закроется автоматически.
2. Генератор списка `[d + '\n' for d in difference]` (читайте с конца) добавит к всякому элементу `d` из оригинального списка `difference` символ перехода на новую строку (`'\n'`), создавая новый список.
3. Этот новый список записывается в файл методом `.writelines()`.

Answer (score 0):

Половина задачи решена. Осталось найти как лишние символы вырезать - кавычки и квадратные скобки

```
f = open('new_elem.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи
json.dump(difference, f, ensure_ascii=False,indent = 0) # indent = 0 запись в файл каждого элемента с новой строки. 0 - сколько пробелов отступить слева
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('new_elem.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(',\n'.join(difference), file=f)
```